# "Cannot initialize conversion" when formatting boot partition while installing arch linux

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, arch-linux

I'm trying to install arch linux but when I run `mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/vda1` to format my boot partition, it returns:

```
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Cannot initialize conversion from codepage 850 to UTF-8: Invalid argument
Cannot initialize conversion from UTF-8 to codepage 850: Invalid argument
Using internal CP850 conversion table
```

I've followed the manual exactly. I've also tried creating a new GPT partition table, with no luck.

Comment: What makes you think it didnt work?

Comment: @davidgo It threw an error message

Comment: What error message? Using internal CP850 conversion table implies to me it continued past the issues it had with codepages...